# Unsuccessful Gradle build with custom XML tag and Databinding

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding, android-databinding, android-custom-attributes

I'm getting the build error described below when I'm trying to run a project using data binding and a custom XML tag in the bound layout:

Layout:

```
<data>
   <variable
        name="data"
        type="com.melontech.sff.viewmodel.DataViewModel" />
</data> 

...

<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@mipmap/placeholder_img"
   app:imageUrl="@{data.imageUrl}" />

...
```

View Model has the following Binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
public static void getImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
    Timber.d("LOAD IMAGE WITH URL %s", url);
}
```

The code that creates the ViewHolder and makes the binding is the following one:

```
@Override
public ModelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ModelListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.model_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ModelViewHolder(binding);
}
```

The build error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
```

> com.android.jack.ir.JNodeInternalError: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
>   cannot generate view binders java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: element public default java.util.stream.IntStream codePoints()  is not a member of the containing type java.lang.String nor any of its superclasses
>       at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypesImpl.asMemberOf(TypesImpl.java:129)
>       at android.databinding.tool.reflection.annotation.AnnotationMethod.(AnnotationMethod.java:49)
>       at android.databinding.tool.reflection.annotation.AnnotationClass.getDeclaredMethods(AnnotationClass.java:314)
>       at android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.getAbstractMethods(ModelClass.java:401)
>       at android.databinding.tool.expr.MethodBaseExpr.resolveListenersAsMethodReference(MethodBaseExpr.java:71)
>       at android.databinding.tool.expr.FieldAccessExpr.resolveListeners(FieldAccessExpr.java:131)
>       at android.databinding.tool.Binding.resolveListeners(Binding.java:65)
>       at android.databinding.tool.BindingTarget.resolveListeners(BindingTarget.java:164)
>       at android.databinding.tool.LayoutBinder.(LayoutBinder.java:250)
>       at android.databinding.tool.DataBinder.(DataBinder.java:52)
>       at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.ensureDataBinder(CompilerChef.java:88)
>       at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:187)
>       at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:184)
>       at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:86)
>       at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:189)
>       at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:174)
>       at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:79)
>       at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:139)
>       at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:121)
>       at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:159)
>       at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:909)
>       at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:434)
>       at com.android.jack.frontend.java.JAstBuilder.compile(JAstBuilder.java:269)
>       at com.android.jack.frontend.java.JackBatchCompiler.performCompilation(JackBatchCompiler.java:219)
>       at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.compile(Main.java:1712)
>       at com.android.jack.frontend.java.JackBatchCompiler.compile(JackBatchCompiler.java:184)
>       at com.android.jack.Jack.buildSession(Jack.java:1052)
>       at com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:540)
>       at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:124)
>       at com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain.convertUsingJackApis(JackToolchain.java:310)
>       at com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain.convertUsingApis(JackToolchain.java:189)
>       at com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain.convert(JackToolchain.java:170)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.runJack(JackTransform.java:230)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.transform(JackTransform.java:198)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:185)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:181)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor311.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
>       at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Data binding is enabled in the Gradle file.

If I move the this feature in a separate clean project and bind data like this:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

Custom XML attributes work like expected and build is successful.

Do you have any ideas what could be the reason for the build error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jd Prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2176952/jd-prajapati) here is my ViewModel class:

```
public class DataViewModel {

   private Data data;

   public DataViewModel() {
   }

   public DataViewModel(Data data) {
       this.data = data;
   }

   public Data getData() {
       return data;
   }

   public void setData(Data data) {
       this.data = data;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
       if (data != null) {
           if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getTitle())) {
               return data.getTitle();
           }
       }
       //Case when title doesn't exist
       return "";
   }

   public String getImageUrl() {
       if (data != null) {
           if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getMainPic())) {
               return data.getMainPic();
           }
       }
       //Case when poster url doesn't exist
       return "";
   }

   @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
   public static void getImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        Timber.d("LOAD IMAGE WITH URL %s", url);
   }
}
```

BTW I've found a way to make the Gradle build the project by changing the ImageView property to the following:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
   android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_160dp"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_240dp"
   android:src="@mipmap/movie_placeholder_img"
   app:imageUrl="@{singleMovie.getImageUrl()}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem you met.
But I found a solution for binding instead of call the getImageUrl directly.

```
<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@mipmap/placeholder_img"
   app:imageUrl="@{data.imageUrl}" />
@BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
public static void getImageUrl(ImageView imageView, Object url) {
    Timber.d("LOAD IMAGE WITH URL %s", (String) url);
}
```

Use Object instead of String. Then it will work. Maybe it's bug of binding or jack.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way...

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
public static void getImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
    Timber.d("LOAD IMAGE WITH URL %s", url);
}


<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@mipmap/placeholder_img"
   tools:imageUrl="@{data.imageUrl}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. I'm still getting the same error.
http://prntscr.com/ep18fz

Comment: check your data model and imageUrl datatype... its correct or not

Comment: Yes I've double checked the validity of data model and I'm sure it's correct. ImageUrl too - datatype is String.

Comment: In a separate answer due to comment length restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to use `Java 8` features and `Data Binding` together. When you add

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

and `Jack Compiler`

```
jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
```

to your project you're getting this error with custom attribute.

**Google says:**

> The Jack toolchain is deprecated, as per this announcement. If your
>   project depends on Jack, you can keep using it. However, it may be
>   removed completely in a future preview release of Android Studio 2.4.
>   So we recommend disabling Jack and using Java 8 support built into
>   Android Studio’s default toolchain.

Here's the official document:
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html

If you're just using it for `RetroLambda` you can migrate it like below without enabling `Jack`.

```
buildscript {
  ...
   dependencies {
      // Remove the following dependency.
      classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:<version_number>'
   }
}
```

And in your app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

And for a second way; -as **Seto** mentioned- you can change your `Binding Adapter` like the following code:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
public static void getImageUrl(ImageView imageView, Object url) {
    Timber.d("LOAD IMAGE WITH URL %s", (String)url);
}
```

This'll also work for you. Good luck.